# Spring Boot /swagger-resources and /v2/api-docs works but swagger-ui 404 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

https://localhost:9444/swagger-ui **404 error**

https://localhost:9444/swagger-resources and
https://localhost:9444/v2/api-docs work without issue so I know it is recognizing swagger
But it returns a 404 error when I try to run
https://localhost:9444/swagger-ui

**Here is the code from** `my pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-schema</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

And here is the code from `my IDAAApiApplication.java` file

```
package com.ibm.idaa.adminfoundation;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;


@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@EnableWebSocket
@Slf4j
public class IDAAApiApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

//  @Value("${encryption.mode}")
    private String encryptionMode="base64";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(IDAAApiApplication.class)
                .sources(IDAAApiApplication.class)
                .run(args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(IDAAApiApplication.class);
    }
```

And here is `my swaggerConfig.java`

```
package com.ibm.idaa.adminfoundation.configuration;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;


@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
//    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String evn="dev";

    @Bean
    public Docket buildDocket() {
        //not display swagger api doc in prod env
        if ("prod".equals(evn)) {
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                    .apiInfo(displayBlank())
                    .select()
                    .paths(PathSelectors.none())
                    .build();
        }
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(buildApiInfo())
                .select()
                //packages you want to be scanned by swagger
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.ibm.idaa.adminfoundation.rest.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    private ApiInfo buildApiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Acceleration API's for IDAA Services")
                .contact(new Contact("Tyler Condon", "", ""))
                .version("1.0")
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * display blank page
     *
     * @return
     */
    private ApiInfo displayBlank() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("")
                .description("")
                .license("")
                .licenseUrl("")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("")
                .version("")
                .contact(new Contact("", "", ""))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Here is the output I get in my console when I try to run :

```
21/11/02 09:46:35 INFO  [Default Executor-thread-186] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
21/11/02 09:46:35 DEBUG [Default Executor-thread-186] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
21/11/02 09:46:35 DEBUG [Default Executor-thread-186] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
21/11/02 09:46:35 INFO  [Default Executor-thread-186] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : Completed initialization in 27 ms
21/11/02 09:46:35 DEBUG [Default Executor-thread-186] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : GET "/swagger-ui/", parameters={}
21/11/02 09:46:35 WARN  [Default Executor-thread-186] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound : No mapping for GET /swagger-ui/
21/11/02 09:46:35 DEBUG [Default Executor-thread-186] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
21/11/02 09:46:35 ERROR [Default Executor-thread-186] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter : Cannot forward to error page for request [/swagger-ui/] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
```

Note : I have tried with trailing slash and without and get same result.

Someone suggested that I use yaml. None of the online guide mentioned this?

Comment: With this: `swagger-ui/index.html` works ?

Comment: I tried that as well with no luck

Comment: I see you are using https scheme for localhost, try changing to http
And if you are using swagger 3.0, the URL should be ending with `http://localhost:9444/swagger-ui/` trailing slash "/"

Comment: I tried it with the trailing slash and I still get same result. Would there be a reason that https does not work for swagger?

Comment: Also I am trying to run this on a Liberty Server I don't know if that makes any difference?